# What does the letter D on the underside of the wing stand for?

Tags: aviation-history, feature-identification

Below is a picture of the [Junkers F.13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junkers_F.13).

What does the letter D on the underside of the wing stand for?

[image]

([Image Source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Junkers-f13.jpg))

Answer (score 10):

It stands for **D**eutschland. And the 366 is the remainder of the [registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aircraft_registration). The 'D' is the prefix to aircraft registered in Germany, think of it as an international license plate. The pre-1928 allocation was D-nnnn (max four digits).

Registration prefixes do not always have a clear meaning though.

For the placement, see here: [Are the size and location of the registration number regulated?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/39016/14897)

Comment: You can even _hear_ the 'D' when you say it aloud. Compare _Dgermany_ and _Germany_. No difference. ;-)